# How to distribute share that sums to 0 without a dealer?

Tags: secret-sharing

I am looking for a protocol where each party generates a share such that $\sum_{i\in [n]} s_i =0$ where the shares should remain secret. The adversary may corrupt n-2 parties, and the parties can be malicious. However, it should be verifiable if the sum is not 0. Is there an efficient protocol that achieves this in a distributed way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I should add homomorphic encryption or zkp to this question as the protocol is entirely  left open. If somebody can tell then please add the relevant tags.